# how to export database from mysql with empty tables?

Tags: mysql

I have a database in .sql format, while restore the database to localhost all tables have unknown data. how can i **delete** all tables data before or after import.

i am using windows 7. mysql server 5.5

Comment: What is the machine you are doing this on? Server, Shared hosting? local machine - windows/unix or mac?

Comment: i am using windows 7

Comment: Just run the command I wrote in the answer on the command prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

phpmyadmin has an option for this task.

Select the database, you wish to export with empty tables

Click on Export

Select Custom in Export Method

Scroll down to Format-specfic options

Select Structure instead of Structure and data

Click on Go

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this query to export database with no data:

```
mysqldump -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] --add-drop-table --no-data [DATABASE]
```

You can also look at other options [[here](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/06/how-to-truncate-all-or-some-of-tables.html).][1](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/06/how-to-truncate-all-or-some-of-tables.html)

Comment: Alright, I understand you've just started with MySQL. You can run this command on Command prompt on windows or Terminal on mac.

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to PhpMyAdmin `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` on your localhost simply login and drop the tables in the database you wish to import SQL dumps.

Then import the SQL dump file (.sql)